# How to use publish profile to change a value is appsettings.json

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using .NET Core 3.0 ASP.net and my appsettings.json looks like this

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Test":false 
}
```

Is there any way that I could configure a certain publish profile (pubxml) to change the value of Test to either true or false ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's very easy. Currently, you are most likely using the `Debug` solution configuration for local development. Let's assume you also have `Release` as solution configuration and want to change certain settings upon publishing to Azure / with your publish profile.

Assuming you are using .NET Core 3.1 (also works with 2.x but the syntax is different), you can this code:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            webBuilder.UseEnvironment(Environment);
        });

public static string Environment
{
    get
    {
        string environmentName;
#if DEBUG
        environmentName = "development";
#elif RELEASE
        environmentName = "production";
#endif

        return environmentName;
    }
}
```

Also create a `appsettings.product.json` where you override specific values.

When you use your publish profile, simply select `Release` as solution configuration in the publish dialog. That way, you application will load `appsettings.json` for default values which will be overwritten by values in `appsettings.production.json`.

You can read more details in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: @MistyD was my answer useful?

Comment: Hi @citronas my entry point is different from yours         `public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();`