# Publish specific appsettings.json file on Azure

Tags: azure, visual-studio, .net-core, publishing

I want to publish a specific appsettings json in my publish folder.

In my .csproj file, I have this

```
<ItemGroup>
<None Update="appsettings.json">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
<None Update="appsettings.Staging.json">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
<None Update="Settings.job">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```

I have two publishing profiles (local/Azure).

In my local folder, everything works fine

[image]

But the when I publish on Azure I am not able to get the correct file:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

MORE INFO:

Azure env settings:

[image]

File property in the project:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Core configures app behavior based on the runtime environment using an environment variable.

To determine the runtime environment, ASP.NET Core reads from the following environment variables:

- `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT`
- `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` when ConfigureWebHostDefaults is called.

The default ASP.NET Core web app templates call
ConfigureWebHostDefaults. The `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` value
overrides `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT`.

EnvironmentName can be set to any value, but the following values are provided by the framework:

- Development : The launchSettings.json file sets `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to Development on the local machine.
- Staging
- Production : The default if `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` and `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` have not been set.

The environment for local machine development can be set in the Properties\launchSettings.json file of the project. Environment values set in launchSettings.json override values set in the system environment.

The launchSettings.json file can contain multiple profiles

**Apps deployed to azure are Production by default.**

Production is the default value if `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` and `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` have not been set.

When you publish your app you can override the environment on the host OS using an environment variable. When .NET Core starts your published app it will read that variables and load the appropriate appsettings.{environment}.json file. If the value is not set, or no file exists for that environment, then the settings in appsettings.json will apply.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1

[How to use publish profile to change a value is appsettings.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60762656/how-to-use-publish-profile-to-change-a-value-is-appsettings-json)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I have set the environment variables. The problem is when I publish the project (webjob) on Azure. Visual studio does not publish the appsettings.Staging.json as specified. I have to include it manually

Comment: When you publish your app you can override the environment on the host OS using an environment variable. When .NET Core starts your published app it will read that variables and load the appropriate appsettings.{environment}.json file. If the value is not set, or no file exists for that environment, then the settings in appsettings.json will apply.

Comment: I didn't get your point. I said that I have set the variable. Anyway, I added more Infos to the answer to make it more clear

Comment: I see now, did you also add your appsettings.Staging.json into Project.json?
https://blog.elmah.io/configuration-with-azure-app-services-and-aspnetcore/